# Existence of a connection $A$ on a holomorphic line bundle $L$, s.t $F(A)=(\deg L)\omega$

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, vector-bundles, riemann-surfaces, connections, line-bundles

I'm reading this [paper](https://londmathsoc.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1112/plms/s3-55.1.59) and at page 67, he states that for any line bundle $L$ over a Rieman surface there is a connection $A$ whose curvature is
$$
F(A)=(\deg L)\omega,
$$
where $\omega$ is a positive form. Does anyone know how can I prove it without using algebraic geometry arguments?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let me expand a bit Henri's (hi Henri!) answer, even if this is completely standard. In general, given a compact Kähler manifold $X$ of any dimension, given a holomorphic line bundle $L\to X$, and given any $(1,1)$-form $\eta$ representing $c_1(L)$, there exists a smooth hermitian metric $h_\eta$ on $L$ such that its Chern curvature satisfies
$$
\frac i{2\pi}\Theta(L,h_\eta)=\eta.
$$
The proof goes as Henri was saying, that is: fix any hermitian metric $h$ on $L$, take its Chern curvature form, then $\frac i{2\pi}\Theta(L,h)\in c_1(L)$. But then, $\frac i{2\pi}\Theta(L,h)-\eta$ is an exact form, and the $\partial\bar\partial$-lemma tells us that there exists a real function $f$ on $X$ such that 
$$
\frac i{2\pi}\Theta(L,h)-\eta=\frac i{2\pi}\partial\bar\partial f.
$$
Now, make a conformal change of the metric $h$ using $f$ as follows: $h_\eta:=e^fh$. The Chern curvature of this new metric satisfies 
$$
\frac i{2\pi}\Theta(L,e^fh)=-\frac i{2\pi}\partial\bar\partial f+\frac i{2\pi}\Theta(L,h)=\eta.
$$

To finish with, if your $X$ is a compact Riemann surface (you didn't mention explicitly compactness in your question, but I guess you just missed it? ) then $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)\simeq\mathbb Z$. Thus (I also also imagine that your Kähler class $[\omega]$ was chosen to be a positive generator of $H^2(X,\mathbb Z)$, otherwise what you say is trivially false...), $c_1(L)=\deg L$ and $\deg L\,\omega$ is in the right cohomology class (namely $c_1(L)$), so that in the preceding argument you can replace $\eta$ by $\deg L\,\omega$.

Comment: Thanks for the details. It helped me a lot!

Answer (score 4):

Let $h_0$ be any hermitian metric on $L$, with curvature $F(h_0)$.

By Hodge theory, there exists a function $f\in \mathcal C^{\infty}(X)$ such that 
$$\Delta_{\omega} f =\Lambda_{\omega} F(h_0) - \mathrm{deg}(L).$$

Define $h:=e^{f}h_0$, it satisfies $\Lambda_{\omega} F(h)=\mathrm{deg}(L)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Henri! Could you please give me more details? Which theorem from Hodge theory are you using? Can you recommend me a reference where I can find it? Sorry about this, but I'm not familiar with this subject yet.

Comment: Essentially, the $\partial\bar\partial$-lemma.